# Is ripple voltage is too high?

Tags: voltage, amplifier, ripple, guitar-amplifier

I'm trying to calculate voltage ripples on bulk capacitors of my guitar amp.
Here's a schematic of it:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f20Jao.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

According to formula Vpp=I/fC, that is Vpp = 0.82/(2*50*0.0011)= 7.4V

I = 0.82, transformer is rated 30W, for rough estimation 30W/36.6V, it's going to be less at maximum load.

C = 0.0011, since two capacitors are in series

Aren't 7.4 V ripples way too high for this application. There are planty of information on the internet about ripples. I'm pretty sure I got it right, or am I not?

The main question is 'if calculations are right, are 3.7 V ripples OK considering schematic above?'

But I more inclined that something is missing in calculation, because I can hear 100 Hz hum, but it is hearable only when ear is <10cm from the speaker. Considering speaker is rated 15W, I bet it's OK.

Comment: @LongPham, how could they be in parallel if negative lead of a cap is connected to positive one?

Comment: Assuming that the load is symmetrical, you only need to calculate ripple for a single voltage rail. In this case, Ctotal = C1||C3 or = C2||C4.

Comment: 2.2 uF is very low for smoothing capacitors. Try 470 uF or more.

Comment: @LeonHeller Um, it's 2.2 mF.

Comment: @LongPham, added speaker to the schematic (although all smoothing caps on speaker are ignored). But the load cannot be symmetrical, only one capacitor can be used at one time to drive the speaker

Comment: @LongPham, although 100nF is so small compared to 2200uF, that is can be omitted. It's rough estimation anyways

Comment: @LongPham, even if calculate considering one cap it's still 3.7 V ripple for 18.3 V line. Isn't it too high?

Comment: Not quite, if the amplifier has good power supply rejection.

Comment: A rough estimation of power supply capacitance for an amplifier is 10,000 uF per ampere.

Comment: That 3.7Vp-p is attenuated by the power supply rejection ratio of the amplifier, which will be pretty good (and spec'ed in the datasheet). The fact you can only just hear it supports this. But more capacitance would be better as Andy suggests.

Comment: @BrianDrummond,  there is nothing in datasheet(https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/cd00000131.pdf) regarding rejection retio

Comment: They call it "Supply voltage rejection" see page 3.